# Multiconditional .isin() filter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to filter a dataframe using multiples .isin() together?

```
df1
co | no | ds
A1 | yes| text1
A2 | no | text1
A3 | no | text3
```

```
df2
co | no | ds
A1 | yes| text1
A5 | no | text5
A6 | yes| text6
```

Filter if the entire row is in the other dataframe
`df1 = df1[df1['co'].isin(df2['co'])] & df1[df1['no'].isin(df2['no'])] & df1[df1['ds'].isin(df2['ds'])]`

```
df1
co | no | ds
A1 | yes| text1
```

Comment: For clarity, can you describe the logic? can you have more columns? duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean arithmetics (`&`) on series are valid only on boolean series. Like what you give for each filtering.

So you just need to apply this `&` to the condition. Not to the indexation you get from these booleans series.

In other words

```py
df1[df1['co'].isin(df2['co']) & df1['no'].isin(df2['no']) & df1['ds'].isin(df2['ds'])]
```

Almost the same line as your non-working one. Except that I apply `&` on the condition.
That is, instead of trying to `df1[A] & df1[B] & df1[C]` (which doesn't mean much. You could try to intersect those two dataframes `df1[A]`, `df1[B] and` df1[C]`; that costs a bit; but not to apply a` &`between them) I do`df1[A & B & C]`.

(Note on mozway's solution: that `merge`, indeed, is an elegant way to intersect the dataframes. But that is almost always slower than computing the boolean series index. Plus, in your case, your logic is already the one you need to compute such indexation. Timeit shows that `merge` solutions takes 3.59 ms per run, while this one takes 0.83 ms per run)

Comment: On large datasets, the merge speed is in the same order of magnitude than chained boolean (although still a bit slower). With small datasets you're just measuring overhead ;)

Comment: @mozwI don't get the same result. With 1000 rows per dataset, I get timing quite similar: 1.18ms vs 4.62 ms (confirming that there is a lot of overhead indeed, since 1000 cost almost nothing more than 3). For n=10000, 4.58 ms vs 12.65 ms. Ratio is going sligthly down sure. But that can't be just overhead, now. For n=100000, 34ms vs 83 ms. For n=1000000, 367 ms vs 834 ms.

Comment: @mozway Same complexity sure. And that is linear, which surprises me a bit, since I grow both dataframe: I would have expected a log(n) complexity for each `isin` (or for the implicit equivalent in inner merge), times the number of rows. So nlog(n). Haven't thought about that much, but my first bet would have been O(n.log(n)), when it seems to be more O(n) (that being said, it is not always easy to distinguish just by experimental timing)

Comment: @mozway But well, it is the same complexity. And, yes, there is a bit of overhead. But at n=1000000 it becomes quite clear that the >2 ratio is here to stay, and wouldn't asymptotically goes to 1. (And even if it did, it would take a n big enough to crash my machine. Plus, it would not be a constant overhead. The part of the timing that is proportional to n is clearly bigger with one method than with the other)

Comment: my comparison on 1M rows was 289 ms vs 386 ms

Comment: @mozway That's strange. One possible explanation is about the parameter we haven't yet explained: I've said that 1M rows was for both df1 and df2, so I take you did the same. But there is still the content that can greatly differ. I've used 50/50 random.choice for the 'yes/no' column. And some `f"text{random.randint(0,50)}"` for the text columns. So, at n=1000000, each rows match a row of df2 with an almost certain probability. More over, there are certainly some identical rows.

Comment: @mozway But, no, it is not that. If I increase that `50` to have less collision (which could have been less favorable for inner merge) ratio is way bigger (431 ms vs 1769 ms)

Comment: @mozway And, in the other direction, keeping the "1 among 6" choice of the original example, I get 320 ms vs 694 ms. So unless there are some misunderstanding on how we build our dataset, it may come from our machines. Mine is quite old (we can see that for n=1000000, under no hypothesis, I have 289 ms. But different doesn't seem so big neither).

Comment: @crrslg I think it probably doesn't really matter, complexity is the same ;) I suggested the `merge` because it is concise. To benefit from a short syntax and efficiency  `np.logical_and.reduce` should do the trick (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = df1.merge(df2)

# or to limit to co/no/ds
cols = ['co', 'no', 'ds']
out = df1.merge(df2[cols])
```

Or, if you have potentially duplicates in `df2`, first [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
out = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates())
```

If you really want to use boolean indexing, then you can take advantage of [`numpy.logical_and.reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) to chain multiple conditions without needing to type all masks:

```
import numpy as np

cols = ['co', 'no', 'ds']
out = df1[np.logical_and.reduce([df1[c].isin(df2[c]) for c in cols])]
```

Answer (score 0):

yes possible see the changes to your code

```
df1 = df1[(df1['co'].isin(df2['co']) & df1['no'].isin(df2['no']) &  df1['ds'].isin(df2['ds']))]
df1
Out[87]: 
   co   no     ds
0  A1  yes  text1
```